# Multiple domains for oauth providers configuration in Grails 2.3

Tags: grails, multiple-domains, spring-security-oauth2

using Grails 2.3.8 and

```
plugins {
  compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth:2.0.2'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.1'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth-google:0.1'
}
```

and the default providers setup:

```
oauth{
 providers{

facebook{
  api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
  key = '11111'
  secret = '222222'
  successUri = "http://localhost:8880/oauth/facebook/success"
  failureUri = "http://localhost:8880/oauth/facebook/error"
  callback = "http://localhost:8880/oauth/facebook/callback"
  scope = 'email'
}
}
```

As I understood, I have to use the absolute URL's for callbacks. That is a problem, as my app is mapped to several domains, like myapp.com, myapp.de, myapp.ru etc.

Is it possible out of the box to provide the callback URL's for each domain?

TIA

Comment: How you manage multiple domains in your application?

Comment: they are defined in the apache config

Comment: Are you able to read the server url in your config file?

Comment: in the config file - of course no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I figured it out!

the solution contains a bit of ugliness, but works like charm:

in my Config I had to change the providers so, that the server name is reflected in provider name and callback-URLs:

```
oauth{
  providers{

    facebook{
      api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
      key = '11111'
      secret = '22222222'
      scope = 'email'
    }

    'facebook_localhost'{
      api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
      key = '111111'
      secret = '222222222'
      successUri = "http://localhost:8880/oauth/facebook_localhost/success"
      failureUri = "http://localhost:8880/oauth/facebook_localhost/error"
      callback = "http://localhost:8880/oauth/facebook_localhost/callback"
      scope = 'email'
    }

    'facebook_wwwmysitenet'{
      api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
      key = '9999999'
      secret = '888888888888'
      successUri = "http://www.mesite.net/oauth/facebook_wwwmesitenet/success"
      failureUri = "http://www.mesite.net/oauth/facebook_wwwmesitenet/error"
      callback = "http://www.mesite.net/oauth/facebook_wwwmesitenet/callback"
      scope = 'email'
    }
  }
}
```

to make processing easier, I remove the dots from the server name.

The same I made for google.